# assign input value to span

Tags: jquery, html

My code:

```
<form>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Min. - 100 coins" id="boughtamount"
 ...
</form>
<div class="finalpriceforitem">
    <b><span class="res_sum">0</span>&nbsp;USD</b>
</div>
```

1 coin costs 1.25$
When user enter amount (how many coins he wants to buy) final price should be visible in this span.

For example
User wants to buy 500 coins
And when he will stop printing sum ( 500 * 1.25 ) should be located inside this span.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#boughtamount").keyup(function() {
  var total = $("#boughtamount").val() * 1.25;
 $('.res_sum').text(total);
   });
});
```

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? What's the problem? Please note that StackOverflow is not a free coding service, this is your job.

Comment: Your title doesn't match what you're really asking.  What you *want* to do is multiply `$('#boughtamount').val()` by `1.25` and return that value to `$('.res_sum').html();`.  So... where is your jQuery for accomplishing this?

Comment: I am trying to do so

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#boughtamount").keyup(function() {
  var total = $(".#boughtamount").val() * 1.25;
 $('.res_sum').text(total);
});
});

Comment: `$(".#boughtamount").val()` does not match what you have in your question, and is an invalid selector.  Please edit your question, hit `Ctrl+m` to bring up the on site editor, and making a working example of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#boughtamount").val()` returns a string. To multiply it by 1.25, you have to convert it to a number too. You can use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#boughtamount").keyup(function() {
        var value = this.value;
        var price = 0;
        if (value != "") 
            price = parseInt(value) * 1.25;
        $('.res_sum').text(price);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Min. - 100 coins" id="boughtamount" />
</form>
<div class="finalpriceforitem">
    <b><span class="res_sum">0</span>&nbsp;USD</b>
</div>
```